# ios :custom NSURLProtocol is unstable

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have an application that using custom NSURLProtocol  want to intercept http request and response with local data. But it can work only some of the time.
Here is the two important function:

```
+ (BOOL)canInitWithRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request {

    NSString *flag=[NSURLProtocol propertyForKey:CachingURLHeaderKey inRequest:request];

    if (flag==nil ) {

       return YES;
    }

    return NO;
}

- (void)startLoading
{

    NSMutableURLRequest *proxyRequest = [self.request mutableCopy];

    [NSURLProtocol setProperty:@"done" forKey:CachingURLHeaderKey inRequest:proxyRequest];

    NSString *resourcePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] resourcePath];

    NSString *ResourceCacheDir = [resourcePath stringByAppendingPathComponent:[@"cache/" stringByAppendingString:MyFileKey]];

    NSData *ReturnData=[NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:ResourceCacheDir];

    if (ReturnData!=nil) {

        headers = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];

        NSString *contentType=[self MimeTypeOf:self.request.URL.pathExtension];

        NSString *contentLength=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%lu", (unsigned long)data.length];

        headers[@"Content-Type"]=contentType;
        headers[@"Content-Length"]=contentLength;

        NSHTTPURLResponse* response = [[NSHTTPURLResponse alloc]
                                       initWithURL:self.request.URL
                                       statusCode:200
                                       HTTPVersion:@"HTTP/1.1"
                                       headerFields:headers];

        [self.client URLProtocol:self didReceiveResponse:response cacheStoragePolicy:NSURLCacheStorageNotAllowed];
        [self.client URLProtocol:self didLoadData:data];
        [self.client URLProtocolDidFinishLoading:self];


    } else {
        self.connection = [NSURLConnection connectionWithRequest:proxyRequest delegate:self];
    }
}
```